# check if username exists with bvalidator (jquery validation plugin)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I'm using bvalidator (jquery validation plugin) to check if a username exists in the database. They have an example on their documentation. However, I have no idea how it works. You can read more on that example here:
http://karmela.fsb.hr/~bmauser/bvalidator/documentation.html#serversidevalidation

I tried creating my own. However, It always tells me that the username is already taken no matter what... I'm a complete newbie when it comes to AJAX. I barely know it. So anyway, here's what I created so far...

index.php (the main page)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#register').bValidator(optionsRed);
});
function checkUsername(username) {
    $.post("checkusername.php", { username: username }, function(data) {
        if (data == 0) {
            ret = true;
        } else {
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    });
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="username_register" id="textstyleid" data-bvalidator="checkUsername,required,rangelength[5:20]" data-bvalidator-msg="This username is not valid or already taken."/>
```

checkusername.php (checks if username exists)

```
<?php

require '../connect.inc.php';
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
if (!empty($username)) {
$username_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$username_result = mysql_result($username_query, 0);

if ($username_result == 0) {
return 0;
} else if ($username_result == 1) {
return 1;
}
}
}

?>
```

**Edit** 
I noticed a 404 error. I fixed that. The PHP and AJAX is working. It gives me a 0 or 1 depending on the text entered in the preview. However, the problem still exists. I think its because of this line of code. I don't really understand what it means. What is *data*?:

```
if (data == 0) {
    ret = true;
} else {
    ret = false;
}
return ret;
```

Comment: Could you please use something like firebug/fiddler to find out exactly what is being returned from the server to the client and post this for us?

Comment: Either use firebug for firefox or dev tools in chrome or IE (press F12)... you will be able to see the AJAX request in order to determine what went in the post and what is returned by the PHP script... then u can figure out if its an AJAX or PHP issue...

Comment: What exactly is the response from the php script that is shown by firebug. Does it return some JSON, or just a plain 0 or 1?

Comment: If I echo out 0 or 1, it would give me 0 or 1. If I simply return it, it won't give me anything.

Comment: Your AJAX response from php is usually echo'ed in a json encoded array where success=true

Answer (score 0):

After looking at it further the problem is your php, you need to use mysql_num_rows around your result to compare with 0 recs returned, the result object itself will only give u a resource id if echo'ed out

Comment: I tried echoing the result out. It works fine. I replaced $username with a username string that exists in the database. It returned 1. I also tried replacing $username with a username string that doesn't exist in the database. It returned 0. I don't think the PHP code has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (data == 0) {
    echo json_encode(TRUE);
} else {
    echo json_encode(FALSE);
}
```